# Can I prevent subfunctions from returning to R environment after running custom function?

Tags: r, rstudio

### Setup:

Say I have two R functions, `x()` and `y()`.

```
# Defining function x 
# Simple, but what it does is not really important.
x <- function(input)
{output <- input * 10
  return(output)}
```

`x()` is contained within an .R file and stored in the same directory as `y()`, but within a different file.

```
# Defining function y; 
# What's important is that Function y's output depends on function x
y <- function(variable){
  source('x.R')
  output <- x(input = variable)/0.5
    return(output)
}
```

When `y()` is defined in R, the environment populates with `y()` only, like such: [image: After defining function y]

However, after we actually run `y()`...

```
# Demonstrating that it works
> y(100)
[1] 2000
```

the environment populates with `x` as well, like such:
[image: R environment after using the function]

### Question:

**Can I add code within `y` to prevent `x` from populating the R environment after it has ran?** I've built a function that's dependent upon several source files which I don't want to keep in the environment after the function has run. I'd like to avoid unnecessarily crowding the R environment when people use the primary function, but adding a simple `rm(SubFunctionName)` has not worked and I haven't found any other threads on the topic. Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Replace the `source` line with the following to cause it to be sourced into the local environment.

```
source('x.R', local = TRUE)
```

**2)** Another possibility is to write `y` like this so that `x.R` is only read when `y.R` is sourced rather than each time `y` is called.

```
y <- local({
  source('x.R', local = TRUE)
  function(variable) x(input = variable) / 0.5
})
```

**3)** If you don't mind having `x` defined in `y.R` then `y.R` could be written as follows.  Note that this eliminates having any `source` statements in the code separating the file processing and code.

```
y <- function(variable) {
  x <- function(input) input * 10
  x(input = variable) / 0.5
}
```

**4)** Yet another possibility for separating the file processing and code is to remove the `source` statement from `y` and read `x.R` and `y.R` into the same local environment so that outside of `e` they can only be accessed via `e`.  In that case they can both be removed by removing `e`.

```
e <- local({
  source("x.R", local = TRUE)
  source("y.R", local = TRUE)
  environment()
})

# test
ls(e)
## [1] "x" "y"
e$y(3)
## [1] 60
```

**4a)** A variation of this having similar advantages but being even shorter is:

```
e <- new.env()
source("x.R", local = e)
source("y.R", local = e)

# test
ls(e)
## [1] "x" "y"
e$y(3)
## [1] 60
```

**5)** Yet another approach is to use the CRAN modules package or the klmr/modules package referenced in its README.

Comment: These options worked like a charm. A little embarrassed I didn't catch this in the ```source``` documentation, but thrilled to have it worked out nonetheless. Thanks again.

Comment: Another option that admittedly is probably overkill is to create a package that contains x